# iMacros - iFrame (Reload/Refresh)

Tags: iframe, refresh, reload, imacros

Is it possible to only reload/refresh an iFrame inside a website that contains many iframe?

---

iMacros Free (Firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be possible at least in 'iMacros for Firefox' **v.8.9.7 or lower**:

```
' you have to specify the following number '
SET numberOfFrameToReload 3
URL GOTO=javascript:{window.frames[{{numberOfFrameToReload}}].location.reload();}
```